# Can't use custom windows themes

Tags: windows-7, windows-themes

Can't install windows theme. When i use .theme file, windows make classic theme. I tried to install patch using Universal theme patcher. But it doesn't help.

Comment: install uxstyle: http://uxstyle.com/ next time ask it on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In win-7 and above version you can't apply .theme file (like in xp) you have to create .themepack file which contains .theme file and other dependent resources e.g. icons sounds etc as well here is a simple tutorial to follow.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24609/create-a-windows-7-theme-pack-from-scratch/